# Hide "Recent" bookmark

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon

I'm a new user of this beautiful OS and was wondering if it is possible to hide the **Recent** bookmark, I've been searching on Google but could only find how to disable it which I already knew. Any advice? Many thanks.

[image: recent bookmark]

Comment: it's this the files?

Comment: yes, it's **Files** with Arc theme.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this, as far as I can tell, without disabling "recent" globally (so that GLib.VFS.get_default.get_supported_uri_schemes () does not include "recent").  You could raise a wishlist issue requesting this ability be added to Files.  You would need to make a clear argument as to why it should be done and get some support from other users to increase the likelihood it would be implemented.